# Django rq-scheduler, Issue in function execution, not executing the scheduled function

Tags: django

I have an Django project, that has some functionality to run as cron job several times i.e(every half an hour I need this functionality to be executed).

Till now the job is scheduling but not executing the function. Here I am attaching the code below:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.apps import AppConfig
from projectApp.views import function_to_exec
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

rc = get_redis_connection('default')
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler

scheduler = Scheduler(connection=rc)

def ready():
    for job in scheduler.get_jobs():
        job.delete()

    scheduler.schedule(datetime.utcnow(), function_to_exec, interval=60, queue_name='high')
    # scheduler.cron("15 * * * *", func=get_dfp_report, queue_name='high')

ready();
```

The above code is in my application's apps.py

and the views.py code is like this :

```
@job('high')
def function_to_exec():
  # some logic here
```

And in my django-scheduler the status is

[image: The status is always in queued]

The status is always in queued state.

Can anyone share the some reference for this to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you start rqscheduler in verbose mode with rqscheduler -v and see update your question with the logs?

Comment: @Colwin I run that command nothing is coming on the terminal, I am getting only "17:56:23 Checking for scheduled jobs..."

Comment: Were you running this before? This is the part that actually executes the scheduled jobs. Keep it running and see if your job gets executed.

Comment: Ok, I will check thanks for the response, can just tell what all the step need to be done to run scheduler

Comment: Added an answer below. Can you please up vote and accept if it answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the rqscheduler from the command line to make sure that the jobs are executed?

The scheduler can be started with

```
rqscheduler
```

Use -v if you need verbose output

```
rqscheduler -v
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler)

Comment: rqscheduler is running but still not enqueing the job (not executing)